# Unable to start Activity Component Info and Java Null Pointer Exception in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, android-activity, android-sqlite

I am working on a small project in which I need to store a phone number and its respective address onto the `sqlite` database in Android. My `MainActivity` has a layout in which a user has two options: 1. He can add a new value to the database(phone number and Address) 2. He can search for the address by entering a phone number.

This is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";
    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "name";
    private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

    SQLiteDatabase db;

    TextView numberTextview,addressTextView,fetchedAddressTextView;
    Button buttonSave,buttonSearch;
    EditText numberEditText,addressEditText,searchEditText;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        numberTextview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        numberEditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        addressTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        addressEditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        buttonSave=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        searchEditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        buttonSearch=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        fetchedAddressTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        try {
            String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                    + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
            db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "table created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String address=addressEditText.getText().toString();
                long number = Integer.parseInt(numberEditText.getText().toString());

                try {
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address); // Contact Address
                    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, number); // Contact Phone

                    // Inserting Row
                    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
                    db.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        });

        buttonSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                long phone_number=Integer.parseInt(searchEditText.getText().toString());

                try {
                    Cursor c=db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[]{
                            KEY_ADDRESS
                    },
                    KEY_PH_NO + "=" + phone_number,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);

                    if (c != null) {
                        c.moveToFirst();
                    }
                    fetchedAddressTextView.setText(c.toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }




        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

the Logcat trace:

```
03-28 11:45:12.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4079): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 11:45:12.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4079): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fivetofive/com.example.fivetofive.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 11:45:12.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
03-28 11:45:12.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
03-28 11:45:12.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
03-28 11:45:12.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1228)
03-28 11:45:12.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-28 11:45:12.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-28 11:45:12.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
03-28 11:45:12.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 11:45:12.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-28 11:45:12.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
03-28 11:45:12.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
03-28 11:45:12.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 11:45:12.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4079): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 11:45:12.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at com.example.fivetofive.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)
03-28 11:45:12.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5163)
03-28 11:45:12.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
03-28 11:45:12.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2061)
03-28 11:45:12.562: E/AndroidRuntime(4079):     ... 11 more
```

The application doesn't even start. It crashes when I run it. This is my first time working with `sqlite` in android. So please pardon any silly mistakes and do point them out.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
Please note: I have solved my problem for now by going for a separate `DataBaseHandler` class which extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`. I still don't why I was getting the error i was getting here though. Don't have time for that now so will come back later if at all I get the answer. For those of whom who will come across this question I just want to say that Making `DataBaseHandler` class helps a lot.

Comment: On which line you are getting this error? Which is your line no 59?

Comment: @Nirali: db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE); this is the code on my line number 59

Comment: hi @abhi_is_learning_android : Please show us your Database Helper class.

Comment: Hi @DhavalSodhaParmar: i dont have a Helper class. Is it absolutely essential to have it? I saw one tuitorial where everything thats mentioned in the helper class is mentioned in the activity class. If you see my code above you will see I have written the code for declaring the varibles and creating the table in my MainActivity itself.

Comment: that is not good way to use sqlite with android.. please create class for that and use it.. because you have to call this method more  then one time. m i right?? and in your code whenver sqlite db never create.. if db is not created then how insert data in table???

Comment: @DhavalSodhaParmar: looking at all the comments, I have already started doing so. If I get the error again. I will edit my question and paste the new code. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: remove this question. if you get error then again post new question..

Comment: @DhavalSodhaParmar: Its possible to do it without the helper class You could just OpenOrCreatedatabase method in the main activity in one tutorial it was mentioned so. But yes, You are right, It would be a good practice to start writing the class separately to avoid confusion for complex apps.

Answer (score 2):

And you have to `extends SQLiteOpenHelper {`

Please initialize you db object with below line

```
db = new SQLiteDatabase();
```

And have you added this line in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Please go through this tutorials

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: I get an error when I add that line to the code:

'The constructor SQLiteDatabase() is not visible'

Comment: You go through tutorials I mentioned in answer. It will help you

Comment: hello @abhi_is_learning_android : in your SQLiteDatabase class (sqlite helper class) make constructor to public.

Comment: I have gone through the tutorial on androidhive link that you have shared, already. that code is not related to taking values from the user. Thanks for sharing the link though. Can you see where i might have gone wrong in the code above. I dont get any errors still the application crashes.

Comment: @Nirali I have voted up your answer cause it helped me when i created the helper class. If u get the answer to this question though, Please post it. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you should open your database before using it.. just put below 2 lines above try{} and then try and let me know what happen.

```
db = new SQLiteDatabase(); // pass context or activity its upon your SQLiteDatabase() class
db.open();
```

i think it might help you..

Answer (score 0):

Please check you get value from this?

```
String address=addressEditText.getText().toString();
long number = Integer.parseInt(numberEditText.getText().toString());
```

if yes then change this lines:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address); // Contact Address
                    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, number); // Contact Phone
```

to this

```
db.open();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(KEY_ADDRESS, ""+address); // Contact Address
values.put(KEY_PH_NO, ""+number); // Contact Phone
```

because in query `KEY_PH_NO` is `TEXT`

```
String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                    + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
```

Comment: Hi @JDroid. I have declared all that's necessary in my MainActivity itself. I don't have a sqlitehelper class so I dont have SqliteDatabase constructor declared anywher. Is it absolutely essential to have the helper class? if not, then where do you think am going wrong? I tried the changes you have suggested the error remains the same.